# Effect of scaling on the mean of random variables

Tags: probability-inequalities

Consider two possibly correlated scalar random variables $N$ and $X$. It is known that $1\leq N \leq N_{\max}$. Given that $\mathbb{E}[NX] \leq 0$, does it always hold that $\mathbb{E}[X] \leq 0$?

While it might appear intuitive that positively scaling a random variable should not change the sign of its mean, the possible correlation between $N$ and $X$ might complicate things. So far, I have had no luck proving it. On the other hand, I could not also come up with a counterexample. That is, I could not think of any RV $X$ which upon multiplying with another positive random variable $N$ with bounded support, makes the mean of the product $NX$ negative.

Comment: An attempted editor suggests that the last line of the first paragraph should read, "Given that $E[NX]≤0$ and $E[N]≥N_{max}/2$, does it always hold that $E[X]≤0$?"

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

Here's a counterexample. Define $X$ with $P(X = -1) = P(X = 3) = \tfrac{1}{2}$. Thus, $E[X] = 1 > 0$. Define $N$ such that $N = 10$ when $X = -1$ but $N = 1$ when $X = 3$. Thus, $1 ≤ N ≤ 10$, but $E[NX] = 10 \cdot -1 + 1 \cdot 3 = -10 + 3 = -7 ≤ 0$.